# Wireless mouse sensitivity is too high

Tags: ubuntu, logitech-mouse

I have a laptop with Ubuntu 12.10 x64 installed. A Logitech M325 wireless mouse is connected to it using Logitech Unifying technology.

The sensitivity settings slider is moved to the lowest setting. The touchpad sensitivity is comfortable, but the mouse's sensitivity is still painfully high.

Is there any way to manually change sensitivity even lower then system settings allows?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Steps:

1. Execute

   ```
   xinput list
   ```

   to find out the mouse's device ID.

   The device name should start with **Logitech Unifying Device. Wireless PID:**, followed by a number. If you have a wireless keyboard as well, there might be several entries. In this case, you'll have to try them one by one.
2. Execute

   ```
   xinput set-prop ID "Device Accel Constant Deceleration" value
   ```

   to modify the property **Device Accel Constant Deceleration**, where `ID` is the ID from step 1 and `value` the desired deceleration. The default value is 1. Try 2 first and increase if needed.
3. If you can't find a setting that suits your needs, execute

   ```
   xinput list-props ID
   ```

   to enumerate all modifiable values.
4. To make the changes permanent, create/modify `~/.gnomerc` with your favorite text editor and add the desired command(s) to it.